# Can MySqlBulkLoader be used with a transaction?

Tags: mysql, transactions, bulkinsert, bulkloader

Can MySqlBulkLoader be used with a transaction? I don't see a way to explicitly attach a transaction to an instance of the loader. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [here](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/170422) by member of MySQL documentation team:

```
It's not atomic.  The records loaded prior to the error will be in the
table.
```

Work arround is to import data to dedicated table and then execute `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` which will be atomic operation. On huge data sets this is potential problem becasue of long transaction.

Comment: Please note that this applies to MyISAM tables, which does not support transactions. InnoDB at least treats LOAD DATA ... as a transaction.

Answer (score 1):

The [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) indicates that the MySqlBulkLoader is a wrapper of 'LOAD DATA INFILE'.  While looking at the 'LOAD DATA INFILE' documentation I noticed this paragraph:

> If you specify IGNORE, input rows that
>   duplicate an existing row on a unique
>   key value are skipped. If you do not
>   specify either option, the behavior
>   depends on whether the LOCAL keyword
>   is specified. Without LOCAL, an error
>   occurs when a duplicate key value is
>   found, and the rest of the text file
>   is ignored. With LOCAL, the default
>   behavior is the same as if IGNORE is
>   specified; this is because the server
>   has no way to stop transmission of the
>   file in the middle of the operation.

I found no discussion on transactions but the above paragraph would indicate that transactions are not possible.

A workaround would be to import the data into a import table and then use a separate stored procedure to process the data using transactions into the desired table.

So in answ