# How Mysql load data in file statment behaves in case of exception

Tags: mysql

I am inserting data into the table with mysql `load data local infile` statement. my csv file contains 50000 rows.

My question is suppose load data infile stament has inserted 30000 rows and at that time power failure or exception has occurred. In this case will mysql automatically rollback this transaction or there will be 30000 rows into the table.

Comment: Check [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491338/will-all-inserts-performed-when-using-load-data-infile-be-rolled-back-if-it-fail)

Comment: Please provide link that points to the question.

Comment: Are you sure that it doesn't  point to the question? Finally you accepted the same answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It mostly depends which engine you are using.

- Remember that **MyISAM** doesn't support transactions, so with MyISAM you will find in the database all rows inserted up to that moment
- With **InnoDB** instead, it will rollback so you will find no rows inserted.